# How to get data by giving id(UUID) in the same CoreData model?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to make a function to get some data in `CoreData` model giving an id in the same `CoreData` model.

---

This is an example function I want to make (doesn't work, just for explanation)

```
func getDataById(id:UUID) -> String { // give an id in model
    return task                       // return an task in model which has the same id of the argument
}
```

if I have this `CoreData` model:

> id (UUID)   | task (String)
>
> ---
>
> 001        |     meeting
>
> 002        |     shopping
>
> 003        |     cooking

And if I use the function like below:

```
let task = getDataById(id:001)

print(task) // meeting
```

It works like this.

---

My goal is to display some `task` data as a list in `WIdget` using `id` data when the `Widget` get fetch data.

(Like values for display in a list and tags to give a value to `selection` when we use `picker` )

Here is the code:

IntentHandler.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension,ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext

    func provideNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {

        // let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TodoEntity")
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TodoEntity>(entityName: "TodoEntity")
        var nameIdentifiers:[NSString] = []

        do{
            let results = try moc.fetch(request)

            for result in results{
                nameIdentifiers.append(NSString(string: result.id?.uuidString ?? "")) // I want display task data using id data here.
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }

        let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
        completion(allNameIdentifiers,nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        return self
    }
}
```

---

**- UPDATED -**

Persistence.swift (Host App)

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    private init() {}

    private let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let storeURL = FileManager.appGroupContainerURL.appendingPathComponent("TodoEntity")

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Todo")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}

extension PersistenceController {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}

extension PersistenceController {
    var workingContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = managedObjectContext
        
        return context
    }
}

extension FileManager {
    static let appGroupContainerURL = FileManager.default
        .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.sample.Todo")!
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Comment: *"if I have this CoreData model..."* - where is it called, how do you access it? any fetch request?

Comment: You need to use an `NSPredicate` with your fetch request. If you post more detail about your model, someone could probably help you figure out how to set up the predicate.

Comment: @pawello2222,@Tom Harrington, Thank you for your comment, I updated my question.

Comment: What is `getDataById` doing?

Comment: @Pranav Kasetti, `getDataById` is receiving an `id` in the model and then return a `task` in the same row in the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a *relation* between two entities.

**Solution #1 - Core Data**

You can create a relation between `Todo` and `Task` directly at the Core Data level. You didn't post enough details in your question to expand more on this solution, however, you can follow these answers:

- [One-to-Many and Many-to-Many Core Data Relationships](https://cocoacasts.com/one-to-many-and-many-to-many-core-data-relationships/)
- [Core Data relationships (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28326959/8697793)

Then, you'd be able to fetch the `Task` associated with a `Todo` item and then you'd just retrieve necessary properties directly from the `Task` object.

**Solution #2 - Map**

Another possible solution is to fetch all the `Task` objects in the `IntentHandler` and then map your `Todo` objects to the fetched tasks.

You can try the following (just an example as the code is not testable):

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext

    func provideNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        var nameIdentifiers: [NSString] = []

        do {
            // fetch todos
            let todosRequest = NSFetchRequest<TodoEntity>(entityName: "TodoEntity")
            let todos = try moc.fetch(todosRequest)

            // fetch tasks
            let tasksRequest = NSFetchRequest<TaskEntity>(entityName: "TaskEntity")
            let tasks = try moc.fetch(tasksRequest)
            let tasksDict = Dictionary(grouping: tasks, by: \.id)

            // map `todos` to `tasks`
            nameIdentifiers = todos
                .compactMap { todo in
                    guard let id = todo.id,
                        let task = tasksDict[id]?.first?.task
                    else { 
                        return nil 
                    }
                    return NSString(string: task)
                }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }

        let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
        completion(allNameIdentifiers, nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, there was a miswriting of the code... and I just updated now `let request = NSFetchRequest<TodoEntity>(entityName: "TodoEntity")` in IntentHandler.swift. is collected. So my `CoreData` has only one `Entity`(TodoEntity). Could you please advise me on how should solve it in this case? I'm so sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Finally I could display `task` value using `Dictionary()` and `compactMap ` by `id` in the same `Entity`, Thank you for your help!